# Tableau does not import all the dates in column from csv file

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to import 'Dates' from 'Date column' from .csv file into tableau. But, missing some Dates in tableau. I don't have any filters in tableau

Below image: Excel file has Dates categorized as 'Forecast' and 'Historical'. Tableau shows only the Historical dates, and forecast dates are imported as NULL. Dates column is all formatted a date in .csv file

Please help me!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI7pP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVaWo.png)

Comment: Can you add the csv  content?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "date" in a CSV file. it is all strings and the specific format used in dates will depend on the setting in the source. If Excel then the format is often non-standard due to confusion between US and international date formats. Tableau sometimes struggles with this and the fields may need some text manipulation for everything to work. Or, better, convert all the dates to unambiguous ISO format before importing to Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change the data type in the csv to string? Or do the change on connecting to Tableau? If you can get the "date" field into Tableau as string, it's straightforward to convert to a date within Tableau.

DATE, DATEPARSE and MAKEDATE all change non-dates to dates in Tableau. (for more details about the date conversions: https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/dates-in-tableau-the-ultimate-guide/#convert)